# How do I load an image into a complication programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, apple-watch

I have a app which has an Apple Watch extension.  I have a UIImageView in the Watch face and would like to have the image change depending on condition.  I have tried this.

```
if ((battery > 30)&& (battery < 110) && (bat = 1)){
           UIImage *lightning = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jag2@2X.png"];
           [self.Jag setImage:lightning];
       }
```

I have put the jag@@2x.png in my watch asserts folder but when I call this it doesn't load no image appears.  If I load it in IB it is ok any ideas?

Comment: What is `Jag`?  Which complication family are you using?  Does `imageNamed:` actually return an image?

Comment: Jag is the UIImage that is in the complications group at the bottom of my screen in the watch storyboard. @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceImage* Jag;  I'm not sure if it returns an image or not.  Apparently not since no image appears when I call it.  That is my question.  How do I programmatically load an image.  I thought this was the way but it doesn't work.  And ideas.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint and see if the image is loaded. If the image isn't loaded the probably your asset name isn't correct. Normally you wouldn't have the @2x.png; you just use the name of the asset in the xcasset catalog.  The asset name would typically be something like "jag2".

Comment: I am a it confused by your reference to the storyboard and an IBOutlet.  You don't use storyboards to provide complication views. Your code needs to fill in the appropriate complication template. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526994/how-to-create-apple-watchos5-complication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working.  I added the images to the assets.xcassett in the watch extension and then left off the @2x as Paulw11 suggested but I did need to leave the .png on to get it to work.  Thanks Paul for pointing me in the correct direction.